# TensorFlow | How I can implement 10-fold cross-validation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

**How I can implement 10-fold cross-validation in this code?**

```
(train_ds, val_ds, test_ds), metadata = tfds.load(
    'tf_flowers',
    split=['train[:60%]', 'train[60%:90%]', 'train[90%:]'],
    with_info=True,
    as_supervised=True)
```

*P.S.*

**Maybe I did 10-fold cross-validation, but I'm not sure.**

```
(train_ds, test_ds), metadata = tfds.load(
    'tf_flowers',
    split=['train[:90%]', 'train[90%:]'],
    with_info=True,
    as_supervised=True
)

val_ds = train_ds.split = [
  f'train[{k}%:{k+10}%]' for k in range(0, 100, 10)
]
```

Comment: Incorrect code. `val_ds = train_ds.split = [`. Try fixing that first.

Comment: All work correctly. But nvm, thank u for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What helped me!**

```
(train_ds, test_ds), metadata = tfds.load(
    'tf_flowers',
    split=['train[:90%]', 'train[90%:]'],
    with_info=True,
    as_supervised=True
)

val_ds = train_ds.split = [
  f'train[{k}%:{k+10}%]' for k in range(0, 100, 10)
]
```